# Scraping data with Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have to scrape multiple data through paginating a page. I am able to jump from one page to the other, nevertheless I can not not scrape the necessary data from the other page. It only returns empty Field. the part

```
item['path'] = response.xpath('//[@id="articleTop"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()').extract()
```

does not return anything. The full code is as follows.

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from provat.items import ProvatItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from urlparse import urljoin
import urlparse
import urllib
import os
from os import path
from scrapy.http import Request


class RegebaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = "regeba"
 start_urls = [
    'https://www.eba.europa.eu/regulation-and-policy/single-rulebook/interactive-single-rulebook/-/interactive-single-rulebook/toc/2',
]

 def parse(self, response):
  sites = response.xpath('//*[@class="yui3-widget aui-component aui-tree-  data aui-tree-node"]/div')
  item = ProvatItem()
  for elements in sites:
   item['url'] = elements.xpath('./span/a/@href').extract()
   for moreurls in item['url']:
    request = scrapy.Request(moreurls,callback=self.save_article_data)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

   yield item

 def save_article_data(self,response):
  item=response.meta['item']
  item['path'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="articleTop"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()').extract()
  yield item
```

Comment: It is likely that the second page has a slightly different HTML structure. Your XPath is rather specific (especially the `/tr[1]/td[2]/` bit), so it might not find what you're looking for. You should try to use class and ID names if you can, because they're more likely to be consistent across the website.

Comment: @Mikk thanks for the response. the reason why I use specific tags in the second page is because there is a table with only 4 `tr` and each of them has only two `td`. I tried it with the class name but same results

Comment: Show `HTML` code for `table` element

Comment: The second thing I'd try is to go on the second page with your browser and experiment in the console with XPath selectors. In Firefox, you can perform XPath searches using `$x("//...")`

Comment: @Andersson sorry forgot about that. here is the table. I want the value in class _aui-w80_
 `<table class='Tabular>'`
  `<tbody>`
    `<tr>`
     `<td class="aui-w20"> path </td>`
     `<td class="aui-w80"> Recital </td>`